# LED Driver Advice Reqd

Tags: automotive, led-driver, led-strip

I'm looking to put LED strips into my converted van. Using some before, it wasn't long before they dimmed or individual leds failed. I was told it was because automotive voltage, especially on newer vehicles, sits much higher (14.4v) than the 12v reqd to drive the strip. Apparently they do not like being over driven.

So, I was thinking instead to drive them at 11v constantly. I understand they would produce fewer lumens but I'd happily forgo those for longevity.

Can anyone advise on a suitable cct? I was thinking of using something like am LM317 to get my 11v constantly, but what would I need to drive the input up far enough to keep the 317 working when the battery is sat a tad discharged at 11v ish?

Hope it makes sense ;-)

Comment: An LM317 is rated for about 1.5 to 2 A; surely your LED strip requires more than that (unless you have fewer than 25-35 LEDs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most dumb led strips have resistors that limit the leds to about 18mA at 12V, and 20mA at 14V. They already adjust for the higher voltage. The issue is cheaper ones use cheaper parts that don't last as long as you think they should. Even some of the expensive ones are just cheap ones relabeled.

Yes, running them at a lower voltage is a good idea. A LM317 Linear regulator is probably not the best as (VIN - VOUT) * A is wasted in heat. This adds up. Anything above 3W will need to start using active cooling. At even 11V 1A out, your looking at 14.4V 1A in, 3.3V 1A or 3.3W wasted.

You need to go with a switching regulator. These commonly have over 80% efficiency, sometimes up to 95%. Even at 80%, the same 11V 1A out as above will only waste 2.2W of heat. An entire watt saved. At 95% its only 0.6W wasted. Most switching regulators can go into pass through if close to 11V so that would solve your other issue.

Any number of off the shelf switching regulators or modules online that would work. Just look for their efficiency at the amperage and voltages you are working with.

Comment: I have explored boost converters, but cannot find one whose input would range from 11-16v with an output that goes as low as 11v. 
Seems those with a variable input is only come with a 12v minimum output! Any pointers?

Comment: @YorkshireDave A boost converter can only regulate the output higher than input. Buck does lower than input. What you want is called a Buck-Boost converter (can be lower or higher).

Comment: Many thanks 